# How to write own Click for my Control

Tags: java, c#, events, javafx

I have a class called `MyPane` extends from `javafx.scene.layout.Pane` and now I want to add my own event (like in C# delegate).

In C# I would do it like this:

```
public delegate void MyOwnHandler(string message);

public event MyOwnHandler Click;
```

to call the event:

```
Click("Hello events");
```

I hope someone can help me to understand the `event`, `listener` and `handle` stuff in java.

Comment: If you extended pane, why not just use the onclick that your custom control inherits?

Comment: the click is just an expamle in my project need an other event